# Thread leak with ExecutorService?

Tags: java, performance

I have a busy travel application using ExecutorService to connect to backend services running like this

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Future<MyResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<MyResponse>>();

futures.add(taskExecutor.submit(myTask1));
futures.add(taskExecutor.submit(myTask2));
futures.add(taskExecutor.submit(myTask3));
for (int i=0; i<futures.size(); i++) {
    future = futures.get(i);
    // do something with "future"
}

taskExecutor.shutdownNow();
```

I found out that it crashes every hour with number of threads reaching the peak like the graph below. Is there something wrong with my codes above?

[image]

Here is summary log when it crashes and it leaves a file called hs_err_pid92053.log

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=92053, tid=0x00007f273e0ef700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 

uname:Linux 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 20 20:32:50 UTC 2017 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 160181, NOFILE 131072, AS infinity
load average:2.02 2.21 2.43

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       41038016 kB
MemFree:         3875544 kB
MemAvailable:   26661144 kB
Buffers:           57724 kB
Cached:         22408624 kB
SwapCached:         1468 kB
Active:         23965100 kB
Inactive:       10993212 kB
Active(anon):   10868052 kB
Inactive(anon):  1649944 kB
Active(file):   13097048 kB
Inactive(file):  9343268 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       8257532 kB
SwapFree:        8253832 kB
Dirty:              9564 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      12490804 kB
Mapped:           171152 kB
Shmem:             25844 kB
Slab:            1053464 kB
SReclaimable:     780424 kB
SUnreclaim:       273040 kB
KernelStack:      529280 kB
PageTables:       101952 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    28776540 kB
Committed_AS:   42016176 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      259648 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359341052 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   6057984 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      247744 kB
DirectMap2M:    41695232 kB
```

Comment: I don't see how we can help you without some details (or *all* details) from the crash report.

Comment: Or without a [mcve].  I'm having trouble believing that the thread counts presented in the graph arise from use of a single `ExecutorService` instance obtained via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`.

Comment: I am pulling my hair to find out what's going on. I used ManageEngine and this graph is generated by it. I still have to figure out where in ManageEngine I can print out which threads are piling up to crash the JVM

Answer (score 1):

You use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` to obtain an `ExecutorService` to run some tasks.  The particular service obtained will own exactly 10 threads for task service, and perhaps one more for management.  Your code furthermore waits for all the tasks it submits to complete, and then shuts down the `ExecutorService`.  Therefore, if this code is indeed responsible for the thread counts you present, then there are two main possibilities:

1. There's a bug in your JVM or Java standard library.
2. The code you present is itself invoked multiple times in parallel.

I rate the latter much more probable.  In that case, if the load on your busy application exceeds the capacity of the host machine, then that might indeed manifest in a buildup of live threads as the rate of new threads being created exceeds the rate of threads finishing and being cleaned up.

Your particular code does not help with that, as, at least in the example, you create an `ExecutorService` with more threads than you actually need.  This will magnify the effect you observe, but the extra overhead is unlikely to be enough to *cause* it.  You also apparently create and destroy `ExecutorService`s rapidly.  This, too, involves unneeded overhead.

Instead of setting up and tearing down an `ExecutorService` each time, I suggest setting up a suitable `ExecutorService` at program startup, and reusing that same service for the duration of the program.  As an immediate benefit, that affords the possibility of much tighter control over the total number of threads used (if you continue with a fixed-size pool).  It should also reduce your thread-management overhead.

If the tasks being submitted do not perform I/O, then it's probably not useful to have more threads in your (one) pool than you have CPU cores, but if they do perform I/O then you might achieve higher utilization with somewhat more.  But not thousands.

Consider also whether you may just need to scale up the host.  For example, serve the requests via a load-balanced cluster, so that no individual host receives requests faster than it can clear them.

Comment: If I create bean like this with spring during startup as a singleton bean and never shuts down, will the threads pile up?


<bean id="taskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" scope="singleton">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="8"/>
    </bean>

Comment: @ChristopherCheng, No, simply adding such a bean to the application is unlikely to have any observable effect.  You would need to also inject that executor and use it instead of instantiating your own.  But I repeat, I think the underlying problem is a capacity issue.  If I'm right then the most you can hope for from such a change is that the problem will manifest differently, such as by the application's response time slowing down over time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out what's going on. It is the limit of the maximum number of threads of JVM that's causing problems.

I have set the following in Linux

```
ulimit -u unlimited
echo 999999 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
echo 999999 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
echo 1999999 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

and then reduce the size of the stack with

```
-Xss512k
```

Answer (score -1):

I've often used FixedThreadPool and didn't run into leaks (even though there can always be surprises given the variety of JVM versions, Operating systems and general coding scenarios). Still the first notes that come to mind are:

1. Most importantly: does your code always reach 'shutdownNow', or could it be stuck on "do something with future" (which I assume involves waiting)? E.g. could it be stuck on some I/O or conditional waiting, with indefinite timeout?
2. Have you checked for other possible sources of threads (other
   people's code, 3rd parties etc).

Comment: My "do something with future" involves SOAP and REST call to remote servers, but those have network timeouts if network fails.
If "taskExecutor.shutdownNow();" is not called because it is stuck somewhere in between, will those threads pile up even though the tasks are executed and not passed to garbage collection?